# Run scripts after establishing PPPoE connection in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, script, pppoe, ppp

I need to change some configuration after a PPPoE connection has been established.
(Change `/etc/resolv.conf`, add routes.)

I made a script, moved it to the `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/` and made it executable, but it looks like it doesn't run. If I run it manually everything works fine, but I want this process being automated.

So for now I have to run `sudo pon provider`, and `sudo /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/provider.cfg`.

How to fix it?

Comment: To see if it actually runs, maybe temporarily add a debugging statement like `touch /tmp/last-pppoe-connection` to the script?

Comment: My script doesn't run on pppoe connection, but others in ip-up.d folder are. Looks like they must be called from other script, but I don't know what one. ppp documentation doesn't covers this.

Comment: In /etc/ppp/ip-up there is code: run-parts /etc/ppp/ip-up.d   --arg="$1" --arg="$2" --arg="$3" --arg="$4" --arg="$5" --arg="$6"
I think that it calls scripts from /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/ folder. But my script doesn't run.

Comment: Don't know what has happend, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts are run with "run-parts" - see man page:

> **run-parts** runs a number of scripts or programs found in a single directory directory.

Filenames should consist entirely of upper and lower case letters, digits, underscores, and hyphens.

> Subdirectories of directory and  files  with  other  names  will  be  silently ignored.